# Django: How to populate form data in template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

So I am trying to have "two forms" in single *class* based view.

**My view is:**

```
class ListAndCreate(CreateView):
    model = xmpp_buddy_groups
    form_class = xmpp_buddy_groups_form
    second_form_class = sip_extension_form
    template_name = "xmpp/index.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('xmpp:index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListAndCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = self.model.objects.all()
        extension = SipExtension.objects.values_list('sip_extension', flat=True)
        obj = SipExtension.objects.filter(sip_extension=1331).first()
        for buddy_groups in group_names:
            for sip in buddy_groups.sipextension_set.all():
                sip_extension = sip.sip_extension
                print(sip_extension)
        context['extension'] = extension
        SipExtension.objects.exclude(sip_extension__in=extension)
        print(extension)
        context['form'] = self.form_class
        context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(instance=obj)
        context['extensions'] = SipExtension.objects.exclude(sip_extension__in=extension)
        return context
```

**My form classes:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import xmpp_buddy_groups
from extensions.models import SipExtension
class xmpp_buddy_groups_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
      model = xmpp_buddy_groups
      fields = ['group_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(xmpp_buddy_groups_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['group_name'].required = False

class sip_extension_form(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = SipExtension
     fields = ['real_name','sip_extension']
     widgets = {
            "sip_extension": forms.Select
           }
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(sip_extension_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['sip_extension'].queryset = \
        SipExtension.objects.filter(sip_extension=1331)
```

My models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
class xmpp_buddy_groups(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.group_name)


from django.db import models

class SipExtension(models.Model):
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    sip_extension = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    sip_secret = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    commlink_push = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    default_did = models.ForeignKey('dids.DidNumber',null=True,blank=True)
    xmpp = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    xmpp_username = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='username')
    xmpp_password = models.CharField(max_length=32,default='password')
    xmpp_buddy_groups_names = models.ManyToManyField('xmpp.xmpp_buddy_groups')


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s : %s'  % (self.sip_extension, self.real_name)
```

I am accessing form in template as `{{form2.as_p}}`. The dropdown appears empty. I want it to populate with `1331`. How can I do that?

**EDIT**: Added models make the question clearer. Pardon my inexperience with Django

Comment: @AlasdairI have added my models

Comment: The syntax you are using: `self.fields['sip_extension'].queryset = SipExtension.objects.filter(sip_extension=1331)` looks like something you would do to create a set of related models for the user to choose from. However, you are trying to invoke the same model that is the subject of the form using what looks like an IntegerField, rather than a ForeignKey field. It isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Since your model has `sip_extension = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)`, it doesn't make sense to set `queryset` - you would do that for a relation like a `ForeignKey`. What are you trying to do there? Why do you want to hardcode `1331` us you have `unique=True`, which will only allow one entry with `1331`?

Comment: Actually I want to populate the template with all the values in sip_extension field in model. but I was not successful so i am trying to hardcore single value first. @Alasdair

Comment: But that still doesn't make sense - you have `unique=True`, so you won't be able to re-use an existing value.

Comment: @AdamStarrh my comment just above.. help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The use case is every extension can belong to a xmpp buddy group and vice versa. I have a template in which xmpp buddy groups and extension belonging to it are displayed. But now I need a dropdown which will have extensions and when user clicks on submit button, it will be saved to many to many field (I even do not know how to save in many to many field). . So that's why I need to populate all the extensions in drop down and next step will be when user selected the extension and clicks on submit, it should be saved in many to many field @Alasdair

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're trying to do. You might find it easier if you move the `ManyToManyField` to the `xmpp_buddy_groups`. That way, you might not need the `sip_extension_form`.

Comment: So how can I assign a sip_extension to xmpp_buddy_group. I can already do that by updating a different form in extensions app in which I can assign groups to extensions. But I want to do it vice versa too @Alasdair

Comment: You could either move the many-to-many field to the other model as I suggested, or add a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` to your other form (which will require more work to save the changes).

Comment: See I have two apps. One is called extensions and other is called xmpp. Thing is I can assign any extension to any number of groups already. But I want  to assign any extension to any groups as well. If I move manytomanyfield to xmpp, I will have this problem assigning extensions to any number of groups. So I am having two templates. One templates assigns extension to groups (Groups appear as checkbox). Same I want to establish in this template but in reverse order @Alasdair

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions apart from the comments above. Hope you manage to get it working.